# curl: (7) Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0.0:6677. (8)

Tags: linux, curl, centos, tor

curl -x socks5://uesr:pw@ip:prot https://drive.google.com/u/0/get_video_info?docid=1uGgYyuU_-s-n68kulQ42p4gJt1RcsmUO

curl: (7) Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0.0:6677. (8)
Please help me

Comment: Thanks. Looks awful.

Comment: +++++++++++++++